# How to enable and disable Frame instead of individual widgets in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an application where I have to enable all the widgets on current window after I click on a radio button. Initially, when I start my application, **I have two radio buttons in `frame1` and I have to disable all other widgets (like buttons, entries) which are placed in `frame2`, and whenever I click on `radio_button1` it all the widgets should be enabled.** In this code, when I click on `radio_button1`, it activates all widgets. **Is there a better approach I can develop, so that it disables and enables the whole frame instead of enabling and disabling each individual widget?** Below is my current code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog

class Gui:
    def __init__(self, parent, **kw):
        self.parent = parent
        self.top = Toplevel(self.parent)
        self.frame1= Frame(self.top,width= 450,height =550)
        self.frame1.grid(row=0)
        self.frame2 = Frame(self.top, width=450, height=550)
        self.frame2.grid(row=1)
        self.radio1=Radiobutton(self.frame1,text='radio_button1',value=1,command=self.enable_window)
        self.radio2=Radiobutton(self.frame1,text='radio_button2',value=2)


        self.label1 = Label(self.frame2, text='Label1:', width=15, background='white', justify=CENTER,
                                  font='-weight bold')
        self.label2 = Label(self.frame2, text='Lable2:', width=15, background='white', justify=CENTER,
                               font='-weight bold')
        self.b=Button(self.frame2,text='save',state=DISABLED)
        self.c = Button(self.frame2, text='cancel',state=DISABLED)
        self.radio1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='W')
        self.radio2.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=50,sticky='W')
        self.label1.grid(padx=10, pady=5, row=0, column=0, sticky='E')
        self.label2.grid(padx=10, pady=5, row=1, column=0, sticky='E')
        self.b.grid(row=3,column=0)
        self.c.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.entry1_Var = StringVar()
        self.entry2_Var = StringVar()
        self.entry1 = Entry(self.frame2, width=15, background='white', textvariable=self.entry1_Var,state='disable',
                                   font='-weight bold')
        self.entry2 = Entry(self.frame2, width=15, background='white', textvariable=self.entry2_Var,state='disable',
                                font='-weight bold')

        self.entry1.grid(padx=10, pady=5, row=0, column=1, sticky='W')
        self.entry2.grid(padx=10, pady=5, row=1, column=1, sticky='W')


       self.entry_focus_flag = False
       self.top.grab_set()
    def enable_window(self):
        self.entry1['state'] = 'normal'
        self.entry2['state'] = 'normal'
        self.b['state'] = NORMAL
        self.b['state'] = NORMAL

class main_window:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        button1=Button(self.root,text='Start application',command= lambda p=self.root:self.callback(p))
        button1.pack()
    def callback(self,p):
        Gui(p)

root =Tk()
app = main_window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you tried? I see you have 2 functions for this but you use `pass`. Maybe try something first and then come back if you hit a wall.

Comment: _"Can anyone help me out to impelement this features"_ - that's really not what stackoverflow is for. This isn't a free coding service. You need to be more specific about what part of the code you need help with.

Comment: Hello sir edited my code and question@BryanOakley

Comment: I developed that function is there any better approach for same one to enable and disable widgets or if I can eanble or disable frame @Mike-SMT

Answer (score 5):

What you should do is to recursively visit all the children of the frame (and the children of its children and so on if (like me) you use nested frames to organize your UI), and disable or enable each individually.

The best way to do that is to subclass ttk.Frame to include the required functionality:

```
class dFrame(ttk.Frame):

    def enable(self, state='!disabled'):

        def cstate(widget):
            # Is this widget a container?
            if widget.winfo_children:
                # It's a container, so iterate through its children
                for w in widget.winfo_children():
                    # change its state
                    w.state((state,))
                    # and then recurse to process ITS children
                    cstate(w)

        cstate(self)


    def disable(self):
        self.enable('disabled')
```

Then create your frames as instances of dFrame:

```
self.frame1 = dFrame(self.top,width= 450,height =550)
```

and you can use:

```
self.frame1.enable()
```

and

```
self.frame1.disable()
```

to enable / disable all widgets in the frame.

Comment: Is indentation of cstate(self) ok?

Comment: It got messed up in an edit. Corrected it now. Thanks for pointing this out.